# Karma tests failing with the good values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm starting to use karma to make some unit tests but I can't figure out why my first test doesn't pass.

This is a controller file :

```
angular.module('balrogApp.requests', [
  /* Dependancies */
])
  // Routes configuration
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    /* $routeProvider configuration */
  }])
  .controller('requestsController', function(Requests, Users, Projects, RequestsComments, CostEstimations,
                                             Regions, growl, $route, $rootScope, $scope, $location) {
    this.requestTypesList = [
  {name: "New", trigram: "NEW"},
  {name: "Enhancement", trigram: "ENH"}
];
     this.requestPrioritiesList = [
  {name: "Low", trigram: "LOW"},
  {name: "Medium", trigram: "MED"},
  {name: "High", trigram: "HIG"}
];

/* ... */

});
```

This is the test file :

```
describe('Requests controller', function() {
  beforeEach(module('balrogApp.requests'));

  var ctrl;
  var scope;

  var requestTypesList = [
    {name: "New", trigram: "NEW"},
    {name: "Enhancement", trigram: "ENH"}
  ];

  var requestPrioritiesList = [
    {name: "Low", trigram: "LOW"},
    {name: "Medium", trigram: "MED"},
    {name: "High", trigram: "HIG"}
  ];

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('requestsController', { $scope: scope });
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    scope.$destroy();
  });

  it('should have proper requestTypesList value', function(){
    expect(ctrl.requestTypesList).toBe(requestTypesList);
  });

  it('should have proper requestPrioritiesList value', function(){
    expect(ctrl.requestPrioritiesList).toBe(requestPrioritiesList);
  });
});
```

But here is the results of the tests :

> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Requests controller should have
>   proper requestTypesList value FAILED
>
> Expected
>
> [ Object({ name: 'New', trigram: 'NEW' }), Object({ name:
>   'Enhancement', trigram: 'ENH' }) ]
>
> to be
>
> [ Object({ name: 'New', trigram: 'NEW' }), Object({ name:
>   'Enhancement', trigram: 'ENH' }) ].
>
> at Object.
>   (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/tests/requests.js:28:35)
>
> Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Requests controller should have
>   proper requestPrioritiesList value FAILED
>
> Expected [ Object({ name: 'Low', trigram: 'LOW' }), Object({ name:
>   'Medium', trigram: 'MED' }), Object({ name: 'High', trigram: 'HIG' })
>   ]
>
> to be
>
> [ Object({ name: 'Low', trigram: 'LOW' }), Object({ name: 'Medium',
>   trigram: 'MED' }), Object({ name: 'High', trigram: 'HIG' }) ].
>
> at Object.
>   (C:/Users/aazor102115/Desktop/Dev/Balrog/tests/requests.js:32:40)
>   Chrome 43.0.2357 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (2 FAILED) ERROR
>   (0.12 secs / 0.105 secs)

So, even with the same value in the logs, the test is failing. Why that and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `toBe` assertion to `toEqual`, they are not the same object in memory.

Comment: `toBe()` is like `===` whereas `toEqual()` is like `==`

Comment: `toEqual()` compares object keys and properties to see if they should be considered equal. `{} == {}` is still false.